# Repository not found. fatal: repository 'https://github.com/justbazz4/Lottery-pools.git/' not found

Tags: github, repository

Getting this error:

```
Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/justbazz4/Lottery-pools.git/' not found.
```

Even when I am sure my repository was correct and I have pushed correctly based on what was asked on GitHub for a new repository.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is an error usually seen when you are pushing to a private repository you do not own.

If you have created that new repository, try first to clone it:

- that will validate your access
- and will allow a push from that clone

But if you are using an HTTPS URL, that supposes you are using and possibly caching in a credential storage the right credentials:

- your GitHub user account
- your [GitHub PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)

Check your `git version` and `git config --global credential.helper` to help verifying if the wrong credentials might be cached.

Depending on the value of `git config --global credential.helper`, you can check what is cached with:

```
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https" | git-credential-xxx get
```